# How to keep graphs included in xlsx file with taskscheduleR

Tags: r, openxlsx, r-taskscheduler

I am creating an R script with openxlsx package that on the end creates .xlsx file including tables and graphs created with ggplot. And when I run script separately works perfect.

However, when I want to create an automated schedule with taskscheduleR package, the task is run but graphs are not included in .xlsx file (only blank plots) but instead a new pdf file Rplots.pdf is created in the same directory. I don't want separate .pdf file with graphs inside but I would like graphs to be included in .xlsx file.

How to overcome this issue?

I look for the documentation but unfortunately did not find anything on the issue.